# Validate certificate for single HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ssl-certificate

I'm developing a utility library that is to be integrated into potentially quite large applications. One of the purposes of this library is to contact a central server using https communication. I would like to handle the ssl certificate validation for this call (potentially just accepting any certificate from this central server) but I ONLY want to do validating for this single request.

As far as I can tell there is a static validation callback for such validation:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
```

I could explicitly specify a delegate from my utility library or hookup an event to the delegate, but this essentially hooks my into the validation process for the entire application and I really only want to validate the certificate for my specific HttpWebRequest.

Is there a way to hook into the certificate validation pipeline for only my specific request?

Comment: The design sound a bit strange to me - by accepting any server certificate you completely lose all benefits of using HTTPS. Is it really acceptable for the applications that are going to use the library? And if so why are you communicating over HTTPS.

Comment: To slow to edit so I'll be another comment instead:
I don't know how to do this if you are using HttpWebRequest but if you have any control over the central server and could change it to a Web Service you could use one of the WCF client side extension points to achieve what you want. Thinking of it you might actually be able to use WCF Web HTTP anyway (not sure though)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Well, in terms of accepting any certificate  I was just looking to accept anything thrown at me (from my local IIS)   during this initial phase which seems like just returning true in the callback. I can't change the central server (the second comment) and don't really want to take on WCF in the library. Regardless of my specific setup, I am still wondering whether I can hook into the validation only for my specific request....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new appdomain from your library. then, inside that appdomain, launch a request to the target server using the custom certification callback that you have. This will make sure that other requests running in other appdomains do  not get your cert callback implementation.

Comment: Well, this seems to be the only way to go about it, so I'm accepting this as the answer